# Find coefficient in linear equation system for non-trivial solution (easy question)

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Find the real value of $\alpha$ so that the system admits solution different from (0, 0, 0).

$\begin{cases} \alpha x + y = 0 \\
\alpha y + z = 0 \\
8x + \alpha z = 0 \end{cases}$

a) 8
b) 2
c) 1
d) -2
e) -4

---

I constructed the determinant and made sure it was non-zero.

$\delta =
\begin{vmatrix}
\alpha & 1 & 0 \\
0 & \alpha &  1 \\
8 & 0 & \alpha \\
\end{vmatrix}
\neq 0 \iff \alpha^3 + 8 \neq 0 \iff \alpha \neq -2$

---

The correct answer is (d). But, either I'm completely mistaken or that is the only value $\alpha$ could *not* have. So, I deduce that the question wording is incorrect. Maybe it should be "find the value (...) so that the system admits solution only equal to (0, 0, 0)"?

Comment: Not at all: this value is the one for the system to have a non-trivial solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equations always have the trivial solution $(0,0,0)$, the idea of the question is to find those values of $\alpha$ *s.t.* there are non-zero solutions.

If you write your system of equations in the form

$A  \begin{bmatrix}
x\\ y\\z
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & 1 & 0\\ 0 & \alpha & 1 \\ 8 & 0 & \alpha
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ y\\ z
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 0\\0
\end{bmatrix}$

Then the matrix $A$ has an inverse unless $\det A =0$. If the matrix $A$ has an inverse (and $\det A \ne 0$) then the solution is $ \begin{bmatrix}
x\\ y\\z
\end{bmatrix} = A^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 0\\0
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 0\\0
\end{bmatrix}$

So for non trivial solutions you need that $A$ isn't invertible.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any other value of $\alpha \neq -2$, you system cannot be reduced, following 3 equations for 3 variables.

If, however, $\alpha=-2$, you no longer have 3 linear independent equations. This extends the set of solutions from
$$\mathcal{S}_{\alpha \neq -2} = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}:(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)\}$$
to
$$\mathcal{S}_{\alpha \neq -2}=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}: (x,y,z) = (0,0,0)+(1,2,4)t: t\in\mathbb{R}\}.$$

One can easily see that $(0,0,0)\in \mathcal{S}_{\alpha \neq -2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I see.

The system is homogeneous -- all the independent coefficients are zero. So, surely exists the trivial solution: (0, 0, 0).

By Cramer, $\delta \neq 0 \iff \text{there's one and only one determined solution}$. In this case, it would be the trivial one.

For there to be other solutions beyond the trivial, we need $\delta = 0$! 
:)